# Ef Core Lambda All records from parent and count of child

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core

How can I retrieve all records from parent and count of child entries along with it using lambda and ef core (C#)?

For example : List all blog posts and total comments for each post.

**Table Post**

Id, title

1, "Hello World"

2, "Hello Stackoverflow"

3, "Hello C#"

**Table Comments**

Id, PostId, Comment

1, 1, "Small world :-)"

2, 1, "Hello world too",

3, 2, "Nice website",

4, 3, "the best language"

**Desired output**

Id, title, comments count

1, "Hello World", 2

2, "Hello Stackoverflow", 1

3, "Hello C#", 1

**How can i achieve the same in lambda with 1 single call to database?**

Please note I do not want to load include comments upfront? I just need all post and count of comments. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Have you written some code that you can show us?

Comment: Doesnt EF Core support Navigation Properties? I guess it does, if so. It should look like ``context.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, x.Comments.Count() });``

Comment: var query = this.context.Post.Select( p => new Post {
                Id = p.Id,
  Title = p.Title
                CommentsCount = p.Comments.Count()
             })
            .AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();

Comment: @RandRandom - Thanks but your solution results in multiple DB calls. If I have 100 posts page size then it would make 100 calls to get comments count. (1 per post). How can I get the desired result in one call?

Comment: ``var comments = context.Comments.ToDictionary(x => x.PostId, x => x); var foo = context.Posts.Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Title, comments[x.Id].Count };`` - 2 calls

Comment: btw cant you say ``context.Posts.Include("Comments")`` this would load the posts with its comments in one go?

Comment: No I do not want to load comments upfront.

Comment: How about you write what you want into your question?

Comment: Sorry, question updated. thanks!